# looping through a column in R and extracting characters

Tags: r, loops, slice

I have a data frame and one column has the protein id's along with a bunch of nonsensical stuff, like the image below. The id that I want is always the 4th through 9th character so I want to loop through the column and extract these to export them to another csv file. The column is also full of NA's which I don't want. I'm struggeling to come up with a loop in R that will slice out the exact characters I want everytime and do nothing if there are NA's and then to stop when it finds a blank, since this would be the end of the list.

mock example of column

```
Prot Id's
sp|IDIDID|PSKSJ_45HELI^sp|IDIDID|FRUEHFJ^HSLHFHG#%$^9y7hiuahl
sp|IDIDID|PSKSJ_45HELI^spuegfuehfw3|IDIDID|FRUEHFJ^HDGFLFHEHFN
NA
NA
sp|IDIDID|PSKSJ_45HELIWUEU^#H63hHU6e^sp|IDIDID|FRUEHFJ^HFGHG:WHFUWH^hfue
NA
sp|IDIDID|PSKSJ_45HELI^spJFBEFBUEBFE|IDIDID|FRUEHFJ^
NA
NA
```

The part that says IDIDID is what I want to get, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Sounds like a `grep` solution.

Comment: `read.table(text = as.character(dd$Prot_Ids), sep = '|', fill = TRUE)` puts all the IDs into separate columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `substr` function to extract the range that you want:

```
x = c("sp|456879|sequence1","sp|121212|sequence2",NA)
d = data.frame(Prot_Id = x)
substr(d[!is.na(d$Prot_Id),],4,9)
```

Output:

```
[1] "456879" "121212"
```

Comment: So I put this in and for some reason I get back just numbers which aren't in my prot_id at all instead of a list of letters and numbers for the id                                                                           `>jeff<-substr(anotation[!is.na(anotation$prot_id),],4,9)`
`>head(jeff)`
[1] "7775, " "2713, "

Comment: Then I expanded the slice to try and put it in context and got this                    `> jeff<-substr(anotation[!is.na(anotation$prot_id),],1,20)`
`> head(jeff)`
[1] "c(57775, 2959, 2960," "c(12713, 19248, 1924"                                               so I'm thoroughly confused

Comment: I'm not sure what I was doing wrong but I just reran it from the beginning by loading the csv file on through and it worked so thank you very much.